# Powershell FileSystemWatcher: How can I tell when changes are complete?

Tags: powershell, filesystemwatcher

**The situation**: I have a .bat script running every five minutes that does some processing on a set of files on a network drive, and then writes the results to another location. Some other process in the organization makes these changes. I only have read, not write, access to the files.

**The problem**: The files don't change that often, but the when they do the results need to be updated promptly. Reprocessing them every five minutes is wasteful. It would be better to only recalculate the results when they change.

**The current solution**: I've rewritten the .bat script into a Powershell script using a FileSystemWatcher object. The FileSystemWatcher monitors the directory and runs the processing script when a Changed event gets fired. That's about what I want.

**The problem**: A change to a file raises more than one Changed event, and I don't want to run the processing until changes have been completed. In my testing, it's always two events that get raised: one when the change starts, and one when the change is finished. I'm not sure if I can take that for granted though. The documentation (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.filesystemwatcher?view=net-7.0) states that "Common file system operations might raise more than one event.", so it's unclear to me if I can take "two Changed events" as a guarantee or if I need to handle an arbitrary number of them.

So I guess there's two questions:

1. Can I take two events as a constant? If so, I can make the necessary changes to handle that.
2. If I need to handle an arbitrary number of changed events, how can I determine which is the final one?

There's been other questions here regarding this topic. The only answer I've seen is to test the file by trying to open for writing; if it throws an error, wait and try again. This doesn't work in my situation as I don't have write access on the files. Trying to open it for writing will always throw an error.

Comment: If the writing process can be changed, then let it write the file with a different extension (e. g. ".tmp") and rename it to final extension when finished. This way reading process will only see complete files (set watcher filter to final extension only ofc).

Comment: You could limit the `.NotifyFilter` property value to `NotifyFilters.Size` changes and employ a heuristic, along the lines of: "if the size hasn't changed in the last N seconds, consider the file complete". You may get false positives, but perhaps the approach is good enough in practice. This assumes that all changes of interest involve _growth_ of the file.

Comment: How did the batch file previously determine whether a data file was part way through being processed when the schedule triggered a run? Maybe just run your Powershell handler at *every* “changed” event and apply that same logic to only process events for fully-updated files?